# Cheap solution to vertical bicycle stand

Tags: road-bike, mountain-bike, hanger, repair-stand

I would like to know if there is a cheap way to put up my bikes **vertically** on a wall (like a hanger that I could put my bikes' wheels on).

I am doing this because firstly they are taking to much space just being parked there... Secondly I have heard people say that the tire gets destroyed if the bike is left for a little while unattended, which is the case.  I have three bikes that I use. The one is used every third day or so, the second one once in two weeks and the third one, almost never...

How do you suggest I build this vertical stand for three bikes for under $20? I have googled this to see if someone has found a way but I only saw some really complex stands and hangers, as well as expensive products.

Comment: If you own the wall, you can get simple hooks that you'd drive into studs in the wall.  Or attach to a board attached to the wall.

Comment: Google `bike hooks`.  Look at the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a number of bikes hanging in the garage by their  front wheels. They are against a wall so that they don't swing about. We just have eye hooks screwed into the roof with a velcro strap around the wheel to attach it to the hook.

[image: Eye hooks attached to the ceiling]

But I would'nt do that for especially heavy or nice bikes. For my families "posh" bikes we have a stand on the floor which was simply a 200x10x2cm piece of wood, with blocks of pine nailed to it in pairs such that they could grip a wheel. If you space the blocks 5cm apart for a normal road bike wheel then it works quite well. Obviously there needs to be at least 40cm between the pairs of blocks, depending on handlebar width. We have it placed about 30cm from a wall which means the wheels are behind the plank of wood that sits on the floor, and are against the wall so they wont roll anywhere.

I would get a picture, but I'm away from home for another couple of weeks.

Comment: I've seen this done, the downside is the bikes still swing a little and either bang into each other like windchimes, or rub on the wall and erode the wall and the bike contact point.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah I suppose its only good for a rough wall.

Answer (score 4):

Free wood from pallets could easily be fashioned into racks that can be fastened to the wall with butterfly bolts.[image: Side Elevation for Wall Mounted Bike Rack]  Also, consider looking for solutions at http://www.bikehacks.com/

Comment: Plus you can make a shelf on the top, and store your riding things there.

Answer (score 2):

These hooks work well enough.  Downside is they have to be into a wall-stud, and the bike pokes out from the wall not hanging flat beside the wall.  You also want something between the bottom wheel and the wall.

If you hang them outside, then the bike blocks access to the screws so its a moderately secure fastening if you chain the bike's frame to the hook.

Note - picture shows screws that are WAY too wimpy for this task.

[image]

These are approximately $10, but I picked up some big solid steel ones for $20.

Comment: The bag that hook came with can be put between tire and wall. I glue them with paint mask tape which doesn't damage wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for the "clug bike clip".

This is a small clip designed to hold your bike in place against the wall.

http://www.getclug.com/

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look stunningly secure, and requires most of the weight to be borne by the wheel that remains on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to two bikes and they both fit under a single bed. Took a few seconds to take off the front wheels, Dollar cost = zero.

[image]

If it was a lower bed (and I wasn't so lazy) I'd have taken the outside pedals off as well.

Comment: OP asked how to hang Vertically, not store under a bed

Comment: @ebrohman the OP asked for a 'Cheap solution to vertical bicycle stand'. I'm just trying to give another option. Have a great day :-)

Comment: First sentence of OP reads "I would like to know if there is a cheap way to put up my bikes vertically on a wall". Whether or not storing under a bed is cheap is irrelevant to what they are asking. Its neither vertical nor on a wall. You should try and improve your answer.

Comment: @ebrohman feel free to create your own answer